# MongoOperations Criteria Query using $or and $and to multiple fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

I am working on a spring boot criteria API to construct the mongodb query but experiencing below error

"Due to limitations of the org.bson.document, you can't add a second '$and' expression specified"

```
    Query query = new Query();
    List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ItemDto itemDto : itemDtoList) {
        criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("item_id").is(itemDto.getClientId()));
        criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("store_id").is(itemDto.getItem().getStoreId()));
        criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("code").is(itemDto.getItem().getCode()));
    }

    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(criteriaList));
    List<Price> priceList = mongoOperations.find(query, Price.class);
```

Expected:

```
db.price.find( {
    "$or" : 
        [
            {"$and" :[{ "item_id" : "1234"}, { "store_id" : "1447"}, { "code" : "XYZ"}]}, 
            {"$and" :[{ "item_id" : "1234"}, { "store_id" : "1951"}, { "code" : "XYZ"}]},
            {"$and" :[{ "item_id" : "1234"}, { "store_id" : "0536"}, { "code" : "XYZ"}]},
            {"$and" : [{ "item_id" : "1234"}, { "store_id" : "1751"}, { "code" : "XYZ"}]}
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ;

```
Query query = new Query(
        Criteria.where...
        .andOperator(
            Criteria.where....,
            Criteria.where...,
            .
            .
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried as per Muhammed's answer and below is what I implemented which worked.

```
        Query query = new Query();
    List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    Criteria orCriteria = new Criteria();
    for (ItemDto itemDto : itemDtoList) {
        Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("item_id").is(itemDto.getItemId()),
                Criteria.where("store_id").is(itemDto.getStoreId()),
                Criteria.where("code").is(itemDto.getCode())
        );
        criteriaList.add(criteria1);
    }

    query.addCriteria(orCriteria.orOperator(criteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[criteriaList.size()])));
    List<Price> priceList = mongoOperations.find(query, Price.class);
```